# Angular Js/ Javascript execute a function until all the content of the array is being used

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops

Question is how to assign  data["random_code"] to each random code from the array but not all at once. If data["random_code"] has not value from the array it will execute Data.service and if response is 200 it will iterate to the next value and execute data service again and will wait for response 200 for the next untill all value from array is being used and then it will stop.

```
  let result = me.records.questionaires.map(a => a.random_code);
    var myStringArray = result
    console.log("List of Code", myStringArray)
```

## reponse

```
List of Code (10) ["50-1118561158114", "50-111111118129911", "50-7111851035611", "50-95354410524", "50-2143566173", "50-49361157339", "50-2961010112644", "50-612511266113", "50-8381637318", "50-6819378387"]
```

## interation part

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            data["users"] = me.records.shared_people
            data["random_code"] = myStringArray[i]   
            Data.service(me, data).then(function (response) {
                if (response.status == "200") {

                }
            })


        }
```

Comment: So, is that iterating through `myArray` correctly? What is the problem with your code?

Comment: I want to execute  DataService.share for every random code without repetition.

Comment: if there are 5 random code then  DataService.share will execute 5 times but it will only iterate to next code if response is 200

Comment: Correct me if I understood wrongly. You want to iterate on random code and call `DataService.share`. If the response of service is `200` then only will iterate through the next random code else will stop the iteration. right?

Comment: yes will iterate to next random code and execute DataService.share again until all element is array is used adn then it will stop.

Comment: random code data will change each iteration.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare i have update my question bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prefer to use recursion for this. Created one method `doProcess` with `myArray` and `index` as parameters. Call the `doProcess(myArray, 0)` with index 0. In this function call service

```
data["users"] = me.records.shared_people
var myArray = me.records.questionaires

    doProcess(myArray, 0);
    function doProcess(myArray, index) {
      if(myArray.length === index){
           return;
      }
       $scope.random-code = myArray[index].random_code;
       DataService.share(me, data).then(function (response) {
         if (response.status == "200") {
            doProcess(myArray, ++index);
            // process
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question and i think it is clear now , kindly review it Sir , thanks